# How to wrap the long word in fixed width column

Tags: html, css

The business requirement is to wrap the text when it exceeds the width. But the second sentence needs to wrapped entirely.

```
eg. Welcome On-board.  
to be displayed as Welcome
                   on-board.
```

But what it displays is   **[First Line] Welcome on-** and **[Second Line] board.**

Any help on how to handle this in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use css you can use `white-space: nowrap`

```
Welcome <span style="white-space: nowrap;">On-board.</span>
```

Conversely, you could just use the non-breaking hypen: ‑

```
Welcome On&#8209;board.
```

Or, you could try using a `<NOBR>` tag around the "on-board". (This tag is Non-standard...)

```
Welcome <NOBR>On-board.</NOBR>
```

<sub>Warning about using `NOBR`:</sub>
<sub>This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.</sub>

Comment: Non-breaking hyphen is unsafe, especially in old browsers, due to font problems. `NOBR` was never deprecated, since it was never defined in an HTML specification; on the practical side, it is the way that works always (even when CSS is disabled).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I added some explanation (from mozilla) about the `nobr` tag. Thank you for the explanation on non-breaking hyphens. I never realised that was such an issue. (I should probably start testing with some older browsers...)